# Solving $f_n=f_{n-1}+2f_{n-2}+2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

How do I solve a linear recurrence relation like

$$f_n=f_{n-1}+2f_{n-2}+2$$

with initial conditions

$$f_0=1,\quad f_1=3?$$

I attempted using the usual technique by multiplying both sides by $z^n$ and umming over all $n\geq2$ and then introducing the generating function

$$F(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_nz^n.$$

Plugging this into the recurrence gives

$$F(z)-1-3z=z\cdot(F(z)-1)+2z^2\cdot F(z)+\sum_{n=0}^\infty2z^n,$$

but now I'm stuck because I'm unsure what to do with the sum at the end of the RHS since I cannot express it in terms of $F(z)$.

Comment: Well, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^n=\dfrac{1}{1-z}$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to express $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty2z^n$ in terms of $F(z)$. In fact,

$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty2z^n=\frac2{1-z}.
$$

---

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just realized. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Equation $\quad f_n-f_{n-1}-2f_{n-2}=2\quad$ is linear with constant coefficients, so you can use standard solve here.

Characteristic equation is $r^2-r-2=0$ has roots $2$ and $-1$.

Thus homeogeneous solution is $h_n=a2^n+b(-1)^n$

Now find a particular solution for $RHS=2=2\times 1^n$ since $1$ is not a root, we can search for a polynomial solution of same degree than RHS, i.e. constant.

Thus $p_n=c$ implies $c-c-2c=2\iff c=-1$

So the general solution is $$f_n=h_n+p_n=a2^n+b(-1)^n-1$$

Now solve for initial conditions:

$\begin{cases}f_0=1=a+b-1\\ f_1=3=2a-b-1\end{cases}\iff \begin{cases}a=\frac 73\\b=-\frac 13\end{cases}$